# Google Cloud Run custom domains do not work with web sockets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I successfully deployed a simple Voila dashboard using [Google Cloud Run for Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run). However, since I created the deployment using a GitLab CI pipeline, by default the service was assigned a long and obscure domain name (e.g. http://sudoku.dashboards-19751688-sudoku.k8s.proteinsolver.org/).

I followed the instructions in [mapping custom domains](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains) to map a shorter custom domain to the service described above (e.g http://sudoku.k8s.proteinsolver.org). However, while the static assets load fine from this new custom domain, the interactive dashboard does not load, and the javascript console is populated with errors:

```js
default.js:64 WebSocket connection to 'wss://sudoku.k8s.proteinsolver.org/api/kernels/5bcab8b9-11d5-4de0-8a64-399e35258aa1/channels?session_id=7a0eed38-77bb-40e8-ad77-d05632b5fa1b' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503
_createSocket @ scheduler.production.min.js:10
[...]
```

Is there a way to get web sockets to work with custom domains? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have in mind that is a known issue, but I'm not able to find the confirmation of it. Maybe a Googler (Steren or Ahmet) will be able to confirm this.

Comment: Have you confirmed it works on the external domain assigned by Knative (that’s shown in Cloud Console), but somehow it’s broken on custom Domain?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google Yes, the `http://sudoku...` urls in my question correspond to an actual service deployed on Google Cloud Run for Anthos, with the first url being the domain assigned by Knative and the second url being the custom domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR, the following yaml needs to be applied to make websocket work:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: allowconnect-cluser-local-gateway
  namespace: gke-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: cluster-local-gateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
    match:
      listener:
        portNumber: 80
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager"
          http2_protocol_options:
            allow_connect: true
```

Here is the explanation.

For the custom domain feature, the request path is

```
client ---> istio-ingress envoy pods ---> cluster-local-gateway envoy pods ---> user's application.
```

Specifically for websocket request, it needs `cluster-local-gateway` envoy pods to support [extended CONNECT](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.14.1/intro/arch_overview/http/websocket.html#handling-http-2-hops) feature.

The `EnvoyFilter` yaml enables the `extended CONNECT` feature by setting `allow_connect` to `true` within the `cluster-local-gateway` pods.

I tried it by myself, and it works for me.

Comment: This worked thanks but also had to make sure `Enable HTTP/2 connections` (under Connections) was disabled

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about your GitLab CI pipeline. By default, Knative (Cloud Run for Anthos) assigns external domain names like `{name}.{namespace}.example.com` where example.com can be customized based on your domain.

You can find this domain at Cloud Console or `kubectl get ksvc`.

First try if this domain works correctly with websockets. If so, indeed it's a "custom domain" issue. (If you are not sure, please edit your title/question to not to mention "custom domains".)

Also, you need to **explicitly** mark your container port as `h2c` on Knative for websockets to work. See `ports` section below, specifically `name: h2c`:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        ports:
        - name: h2c
          containerPort: 8080
```

I also see that the response code to your requests is HTTP 503, likely indicating a server error. Please check your application’s logs.