# Cloud run + websockets behind reverse proxy fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, google-cloud-run

For some time I've been using ambassador/emissary as an API gateway, and I really want to use it as a means to talk to cloud run through custom domains.

My pattern is

```
(client) -> (ambassador/emissary) -> (cloud run) -> (fastapi)
```

For ambassador/emissary to talk to cloud run altogether (not just throw a 404), I needed to rewrite the `host` header (as mentioned [here](https://siipo.la/blog/fixing-the-host-header-when-running-a-reverse-proxy-on-google-cloud-run)) (`host_rewrite` option in ambassador/emissary). However, websocket connections doesn't work for some reason. I have successfully made this work with

```
(client) -> (ambassador/emissary) -> (GKE Autopilot) -> (fastapi)
```

The client throws a 1006 and it feels like if there is some wrong expectations now which header values the cloud run expects.

The ambassador mapping is [here](https://github.com/databutton/ws-repro/blob/main/mapping.yaml)

Does anyone have cloud run working with websocket on custom domains?

### Update

Using firebase hosting as a router instead, meaning

```
(client) -> (firebase hosting rewrite) -> (cloud run) -> (fastapi)
```

doesn't work either with a websocket setup.

Comment: can you refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63406952/15774176), is it helpful?

Comment: I don't think so, at least to my understanding. As I'm using managed cloud run I can't send custom manifests into the running cluster (I think!).

Comment: does your issue similar to this [git case](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45139)? if not can you concisely elaborate the main cause it will be helpful in troubleshooting , can u also share the complete error that you are getting?